# For loop in data grid view

Tags: visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I'm planning to add several rows in data grid view.

```
For index1 As Double = 0.2 To 1 Step 0.02      
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(index1)
    Next index1
```

I kept getting errors. Any ideas?

Comment: please post your errors mate (and nice nickname. welcome to StackOverflow)

Comment: 'First Real Trial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: First Real Trial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'First Real Trial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: First Real Trial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[7164] First Real Trial.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: haha sorry about that

Comment: I already tried converting the data type to string, It doesn't work also. So far, the error happens when i tried to add loop to it

Comment: please post the error by editing your question :)